# Write inline style in the head section

Tags: php, yii, yii2

With registercssfile one can register the css which comes as a link in head section . How to write the same within the style tags.

Answer (score 1):

Use [registerCss](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerCss%28%29-detail) method of [yii\web\View](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html).

Example of usage inside view:

```
$this->registerCss('body { }');
```

From controller:

```
$this->view->registerCss('body { }');
```

From anywhere you can also access it like this:

```
use Yii;

...

Yii::$app->view->registerCss('body { }');
```

**P.S.** Note that is considered bad practice.

Comment: There is css file , how to write the contents of it in the head.

Comment: You asked about putting it in `<style></style>` tags. To include it from the file use `registerCssFile()` as you mentioned at the very beginning, it will generate `link`. Or use asset bundles.